# Dompdf font letter swaped in shruti font

Tags: laravel, dompdf

Dompdf font letter swaped with shruti font

[image]

Original

[image]

Result

Image 1 is original content and Image 2 is the result

please help us to resolve this issue

Comment: There are similar issues when using other language characters. The underlying cause has not yet been resolved.

Comment: HELP US NOT YET RESOLVED